# How to properly send data via sockets between java and c?

Tags: java, c, sockets

I am currently trying to send strings via sockets between Java and c. I am able to either send a String to the client (c) from the server (java), or vice versa, but not BOTH, which is how I need to communicate between the two. In my c (client) code, as soon as I insert the read portion, the code haults.

Here are my two portions of code. It is safe to assume the connection between the sockets is successful.

java:

```
private void handshake(Socket s) throws IOException{
    this.out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String key = in.readLine(); //get key from client
    if(!key.equals(CLIENTKEY)){
        System.out.println("Received incorrect client key: " + key);
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("received: " + key);
    System.out.println("sending key");
    out.println("serverKEY"); //send key to client
    System.out.println("sent");
}
```

c:

```
    int n;
    n = write(sockfd,"clientKEY",9);
    if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
    }
  n = read( sockfd,recvBuff,255 );
  if (n < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
    }
  printf("Here is the message: %s\n",recvBuff);
```

Comment: Does it display an error message when it halts?  If so, what is the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your C send code:

```
char clientKey[] = "clientKEY\n"
n = write(sockfd,clientKey, strlen(clientKey));
```

It's better to use a variable for clientKey and then call strlen so you don't have to count char's manually.  As Jiri pointed out, Java's readLine function is probably expecting a newline char that it's never getting so it hangs.

Comment: ah!! that was obvious. Thank you! I have to remember println() in java appends the \n character.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the C/C++ server sends a `clientKEY` message to the Java client. The Java client reads a line, i.e. waits till it receives the `\n` character from the C/C++ server. However, it is never sent by the C/C++ server and so the Java client waits... forever.